# Jackson what to set the timezone for JSON parsing?

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

Feeling a bit lost here. I parse a "date" in this format:

```
@JsonProperty("earliest_pick_up_time")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "HH:mm", timezone = "Europe/Berlin")
private Date earliestPickUpTime;
```

But its not really a date, as the source is an hour and minute, like 14:43 or 16:12 etc.

What is the timezone here? The timezone of what? The server? The device? Do I need to count for the location of the device so it always get displayed correctly? 14:43 is 14:43 regardless if the user is in Berlin or Australia in this case. Do I need to know the location of the server?

The user sets this time and date earlier, so does the timezone refer to that?

If I dont explicitly set the time zone I get wrong dates. Now I set the time zone as MY time zone but I'm not sure if this is even correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date is probably not a good object since you have to parse HH:mm.

Dates represent a certain instance in time after 1/1/1970 UTC. And you can't represent that with only an hour from 0-23

You should probably look into making a custom HourMinute object and a custom Deserializer/Serializer

You would also take timezone into consideration as some sort of offset.

What if i'm in berlin and i set my earliest pickup time to 1.00

Is the time -5am in new york?

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up using a string and create the dates later

Answer (score 0):

Server's timezone and client's timezone can be different. I would set my server's default timezone to UTC.
Along with time, I would force clients to send  timezone information in every request (may be as a request parameter or header). In server I would parse it to UTC and persist in db as timestamp.
When retrieved from db, it will be UTC. I would convert to client's timezone again and send it back.

So ideally, server's location doesn't matter as long as you're setting server's default timezone. You can directly set it in server or set it in application on startup. However client's location really matters. You may want to show them time in their own timezone. Do not add timezone offsets manually. Use built-in frameworks to handle daylight saving etc.